# iOS willFinishLaunchingWithOptions not passing launchOptions to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I'm launching my app by tapping on a remote push notification sent through firebase. When the app launches I have a breakpoint set in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and I can see the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` there in the launchOptions dictionary.

When I move forward to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` the launchOptions are `nil`. I have no idea where my remote notification is going or why this is happening, but it's getting lost between `willFinish` and `didFinish`. Any ideas?

Edit:

My notification payload looks like this, I'm using Firebase Admin on Node to send:

```
{
  data: {
    route: "string for app to parse and route to a screen"
  },
  notification: {
    badge: number,
    body: string,
    title: string
  }
}
```

I'm also setting `content_available` through the Firebase SDK, and all the correct information shows up in launch options, as long as I look in `willFinish`.

Here's what launchOptions is showing me:
[image: Breakpoint set in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions]

Comment: This is not expected. No clue, just some thoughts. Is the iPhone locked? Or does your notification have a specific category set on it? Maybe it has something do with those? Can you share the payload of your notification? What's in its `userInfo`?

Comment: Made some edits. The phone isn't locked nor does the notification have a category. Delivery seems a-ok. Is there somewhere I can get `userInfo` from? I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry this: `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from background or closed")
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}`

Comment: Are you getting the `didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse` callback? Not a solution to your problem, but perhaps whatever you need to do you can do in there...

Comment: No, this is specifically when the app is initially open from a closed (not background) state.

Comment: that function will still give you a callback if app is launched from tapping. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter): "the response parameter contains the identifier for that action. _The response can also indicate that the user dismissed the notification interface, or launched your app, without selecting a custom action'_

Comment: In your `will` implementation try returning NO instead of YES.